# Changing the default view of "The Events Calendar" for mobile

Tags: functions, javascript, mobile

I'm using "The Events Calendar" plugin on my site at https://divealaska.net/events/. I’m looking to set the default view to List but only for the mobile. So far I’ve come up with trying to add a bit of Javascript to the header that would forward them to the /events/list/ page, but i cant’ seem to get wordpress to let me add it in just for the events page. Here’s my current code:

```
function load_js_assets() {
    if( is_page( 'events' ) ) {
        ?>
            <!-- FORWARD IF MOBILE -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                <!--
                if (screen.width <= 699) {
                    document.location = "/events/list/";
                }
                //-->
            </script> 
        <?php
    } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');
```

I’ve placed that in the functions file of my theme. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`/events/` is the address of `tribe_events` posts archive, not of a single page, therefore the [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) conditional tag does not work. You should use [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive)

```
if( is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' ) ) {
```